# How to handle question with many highly voted answers that only answer a related question?

Tags: discussion

[How do I force "git pull" to overwrite local files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1125968/120398) is a question on Stack Overflow about handling a particular error that occurs with the `git` version control system: when checking out a new branch that overwrites files that aren't committed to the repository. This is very explicitly clear in the question (and has been ever since first asked).

There is an interesting related question: how to handle another error that occurs when checking out a new branch that overwrites files that are committed to the repository, but have been locally changed.

The two scenarios require very different solutions. Some of the very highly-voted answers (including the accepted answer with `3859` votes), including many others are solving the second related problem, and not answering the original question. This obscures the answers that are actually helpful as you have to search through many to find the useful ones.

How should this situation be handled? Is it possible to split answers off and attach them to a different question?

Comment: No, it's not possible to transplant answers - a user would need to delete it and repost it manually.

Comment: Thanks. So how can this situation be addressed to make this information more correctly classified?